# extract the latest non zero revenue row

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

Sample data:

Input :

```
product_name| snapshot_time (varchar)|  revenue  (varchar)  |
product_A   | 2021-07-01            |    $0.0              |
product_A   | 2021-04-01            |    $30.12            |
product_A   | 2021-06-01            |    $12.23            |
product_B   |  ......               | ......               |
product_C   | ......                | .......              |
  ......
```

Output should be:

```
product_name| snapshot_time (varchar)|  revenue  (varchar)   |
product_A   | 2021-06-01             |    $12.23             |
product_B   |  lastest   time        | non zero value        |
product_C   | lastest   time         |non zero value         |
  ......
```

#### The requrement is that:

For each product:

- if there is any **non zero revenue** records:

extract the **latest non zero revenue** row

- if all records are `$0.0`:

extract the **latest `$0.0` revenue** row

---

I tried:

```
with t as (
select *, row_number() over(partition by product_name order by snapshot_time desc, revenue desc) as rnk 
from sample_data) 
SELECT product_name, snapshot_time, revenue
FROM t where rnk = 1;
```

but it's wrong because it might extract the `$0.0` row.

Comment: `but it's wrong because it might extract the $0.0 row` ... if a product group really only has zero revenue records _and_ you insist on always selecting one record per group, then you might admit some zero revenue records in your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this version:

```sql
WITH t AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_name
                                 ORDER BY revenue > 0 DESC, snapshot_time DESC) rn
    FROM sample_data
)

SELECT product_name, snapshot_time, revenue
FROM t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: No. The sample data is the result of a `parition by` of some columns.. Let me edit the question to make it more clearer.

Comment: @Rick I think you just need to add a `WHERE` clause to the CTE, see the above.  Note that if you want to guarantee that every product would always have a record, then you also must admit that its revenue might be zero.

Comment: Oh sorry ... If there's only `$0.0` records, I need to pick one too. So `$0.0` should not be filtered with `where` I think?

Comment: ...then the query in your question is already correct.  You must have some other problem in this case.

Comment: I've updated my question again. T_T. If revenues of `product_A` are all `$0.0`, I need to get the one with latest `snapshot_time` and `revenue = $0.0`.

Comment: `ORDER BY revenue DESC, snapshot_time DESC` gives you the largest revenue row, not the lastest row with non zero revenue. This is incorrect. As for my example, I need to get the  `$12.23` row while your answer would get the `$30.12` row

Comment: @Morty I have updated again with what I perceive to be the correct logic.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . The `if` is superfluous.  MySQL can handle a boolean for ordering -- just remember that `true` > `false`.

Comment: @Gordon Yes, I realized this after the 10th edit.  The OP was fairly unclear, and lacking in detail.  Check the edit histories of the Q&A to see this.